# Looking for ASP.NET Shared Calendar/Scheduler Control

Tags: asp.net, calendar, shared, scheduler

Can someone recommend an ASP.NET calendar/scheduler control that allows the calendar to be shared?  The shared part is important.

Free is good but paid is fine.  I would rather it not be part of a control bundle as I just need this one control.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider this JQuery plugin, which is pretty advanced: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

There are other third-party components like Telerik's RadScheduler And DevExpress's AspxScheduler controls.

HTH.

Comment: Looks like the JQuery one doesn't do sharing.  The other ones are part of a bundle.  Thanks though.

Comment: What do you mean by sharing though, aren't we really talking more about an application function, rather than a specific feature of a control?

Comment: I mean where a supervisor can see the scheduled events of his people.

Comment: Yes, I have several apps where we done that: that is not a feature of a particular control, its a feature of the application.  Rather than trying to find a control that has that feature built in, why not just find a good scheduler control, and build this into your application as a feature?  The way we did it is add a drop down with the employee names, and when selected, refresh the scheduled view.